# Single Slit/Double Slit path differences

Tags: waves, double-slit-experiment, interference, diffraction

When diffracting light through a **double** slit, I understand that the two sources must arrive on the screen m(wavelengths) out of phase [where m is any **whole number**], in order for a bright fringe to form. This is due to the fact that a path difference of mλ would result in constructive interference, i.e. reinforcement, and hence maximum intensity would be detected at this point.

However, when diffracting light through a **single** slit, the situation is different. The two sources must arrive on the screen (m+1/2)λs out of phase, e.g., λ/2, 3λ/2, 5λ/2 etc, for constructive interference. I cannot understand why this is the case, and my physics teacher cannot either. Why would this result in constructive interference and not destructive?

The sources I'm referring to are: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7CmbItRjM-Y&ab_channel=khanacademymedicine
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T-kgoxhFSmU&ab_channel=khanacademymedicine

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you watch the video to see how he explained it?

Comment: It shows you how it considers the single slit as two sources, and they're only 15 minutes long

Comment: I watched the video. He is talking about destructive interference for the single slit versus constructive interference for the double slit.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform, ..."if there is only one slit, how can there be two sources?" Because the slit, no matter how small, has a certain _width_. It's similar to how light through a point-like aperture results in an Airy disk.