# Single slit and double slit interference

Tags: optics, waves, electromagnetic-radiation, double-slit-experiment, interference

I skimmed [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/230372/289358) and [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/498207/) about the title subject but I am still unclear. What are the **differences** and similarities between **single slit and double slit** interference patterns?

Comment: You should read a few chapters of a book on fourier optics, not skim a few answers here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expressions for single slit and double slit Fraunhofer diffraction look like:

$$I(\theta )=I(0)\ \text{sinc}^2\beta$$
$$I(\theta)=I(0)\ (\text{sinc}^2\beta)(\cos^2\alpha)$$
where $\alpha=(\pi a\sin\theta)/\lambda$ and $\beta=(\pi b\sin\theta)/\lambda$ and as usual $a$ and $b$ represent the distance between the slits and width of slits. Also

$$\text{sinc}( u)\equiv\frac{\sin u}{u}$$

---

OP is asking for the similarity and difference between the patterns. Now These are two different functions but you can plot them to see what are differences and similarity. This task, I left, to OP. :) You can  find the [plot here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/liy84jdiun). Focus on envelope for similarity.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at single edge Diffraction patterns: https://images.app.goo.gl/RSYzmToh96thgAfM6

A single slit has two edges with diffraction patterns going opposite directions.
A double slit has four edges with diffraction patterns going opposite directions and overlapping each other.